# Stationary Distribution of a discrete-time markov chain

Tags: probability-distributions, recurrence-relations, markov-chains

> Define a discrete-time markov chain with state space $I=\{0, 1, ..., d\}$ and transition probabilities given by:
>
> $$p_{i, i+1} = \left(\frac{d-i}{d}\right)^2$$
>   $$p_{i, i} = \frac{2i(d-i)}{d^2}$$
>   $$p_{i, i-1} = \left(\frac{i}{d}\right)^2$$
>   $$p_{i,j} = 0 \quad , \text{ otherwise}.$$
>
> How can one find its stationary distribution $\Pi = [\pi_0, ..., \pi_d]$?

I managed to calculate $\Pi$ for some small examples with $d=1,2,3$ and also could find a recurrence relation using the detailed-balance equation:

$$ \pi_i p_{i,j} = \pi_j p_{j,i} $$ concluding that:

$$ \pi_{i+1} = \left(\frac{d-i}{i+1}\right)^2\pi_i \quad, \quad i > 0$$

But I don't know how to find the answer for the general case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You solve the equation $\pi P = \pi$. $P$ is a tri-diagonal matrix (except for the end points), so it is not too bad to solve.

The system of equations is:
for every $j>0$
$\pi_j(1-p_{jj}) = \pi_{j-1}p_{j,j-1}+\pi_{j+1}p_{j, j+1}$

For $j=0$ in particular,

$\pi_0(1-p_{00}) = \pi_{1}p_{0,1}$. Now you can work recursively (difference equation)

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst wouldn't it be: $\pi_j = \sum_{k=0}^{d}{\pi_kp_{k, j}} = \pi_{j-1}p_{j-1, j} + \pi_{j}p_{j, j} + \pi_{j+1}p_{j+1, j}$. ?

Comment: yeah i just put the middle term on LHS

Comment: Solving the recurrence I stated in the problem I got to this awkward solution:
$$ \pi_0 = \left( 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{d-1}{(\prod_{i=0}^{k}{\frac{d-i}{i+1}})^2}\right)^{-1}$$ and $\pi_i = \left(\left(\frac{d-(i-1)}{i}\right)^2\pi_{i-1}\right)$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Actually my doubt is why you swaped the probabilities indexes in $p_{j,j\pm1} \leftrightarrow p_{j\pm1,j}$

Comment: yes typo, swap them back

Comment: I'm afraid your recurrence relation doesn't have a nice closed form. Mathematica returns
$$
\texttt{1/(1 + d + 2 HarmonicNumber[d] - 2 d HarmonicNumber[d] + 
   HarmonicNumber[d, 2] - 2 d HarmonicNumber[d, 2] + 
   d^2 HarmonicNumber[d, 2])}
$$
for $\pi_0$.